# Does Real Eigenvalues mean it is an hermitian Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let us say I know that a given $N\times N$ matrix has all its eigenvalues as real, does it mean, it is hermitian. How do I prove (or disprove) that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: think about the following matrix:

$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1\\ 
0 & 1\end{array}\right)
$$

Comment: +1, though it might be useful to ponder a matrix like $$\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$ as well.

Answer (score -3):

ABSOLUTELY NOT. It is easy to construct cases with real eigenvalues, even complex coefficients, and not Hermitian.